# Trusted_Connection isn't working anymore

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, database-connection, connection-string

A year ago on this very setup it was working.  I've been working on completely unrelated stuff and now I'm back to the old project--and I'm getting login failed for user 'servername'\GUEST.

Note:  GUEST, not my username.

Workstation:  Win 7/64 Ultimate.

Server: SQL Server, XP Pro

The workstation has a drive letter mapped to a directory on the server, auto-restored at boot.

The connection string is:  server='servername'; Trusted_Connection=yes

It's not specifying a database as the objective of this code is to create the database.

I'm not aware of any system changes beyond all the updates Microsoft sends.  Both boxes are fully patched.

Edit:  Yes, they are the same domain.  This used to work.

Edit:  I reproduced it with a trivial project:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ConnectionString = "Server=Hydrogen; Trusted_Connection=yes";
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    Connection.Open();
                    Connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception E)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

produces:

Login failed for 'HYDROGEN\Guest'.

Edit:  It mislead me before, the server log says:

Login failed for user 'HYDROGEN\Guest'.  Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error.  Check for previous errors.  [CLIENT: workstation's-ip]

Comment: Are both computers members of the same domain

Comment: can you telnet to the server? port 1433

Comment: @LuisLL There's something there but it sent no text identifying itself.

Comment: @LorenPechtel see my response below

Comment: @LorenPechtel What type of application is this? Web? Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I would start doing following tests in the **server**.

1. check the the SQL services are working: **SQL Server** & **SQL Browser** services at least
2. check that you can connect to the SQL Server from the local station itself. use OSQL or SSMS
3. check that the firewall at the Server is Off or allows access to *critical* SQL Ports like  1433 for TCP protocol and I believe that 445 & 139 for Named Pipes
4. in SQL Configuration Manager check that you have TCP and Named Pipes enabled (assuming that you are using SQL 2005 and up)

Comment: I can log in with the management console on the XP box no problem.  Note that the error has a username of guest, not the correct username.  I think the problem is on the client side.

Comment: I just noticed that the connection string doesn't mention the server name. Is that right?

Comment: No, that's my forgetting how this system works and putting angle brackets around the word servername.  The HTML stripper nuked it.  Fixed.